# How to press the link in the datagridview1 and go to the another form?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

How to press the link in the datagrid and go to the another form?

[image]

Code:

```
foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables["timeentryrangedetails"].Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewLinkColumn link = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();             
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(link);
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            link.Text = "Details";
            link.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = link.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["CutoffID"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["StartDate"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["EndDate"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["withTax"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["SSS"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["PhilHealth"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item["Pagibig"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value = item["status"].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by _”go to the another form”_ ? This implies that the “another form” is already displayed and perhaps you simply want to gain focus on this form? This is doable with little effort IF the other form is from THIS code. Is the “other” form exposed to this code to actually give it focus, OR is it some other programs form? You may want to be more specific on what exactly you mean by “another form.”

Answer (score 0):

you can use the DataGridViewLinkColumn.

For more information [read it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ebc2afcc-aa20-4530-a490-3703af04cabb/datagridview-hyperlink-click-show-another-form?forum=winforms)

Comment: DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
            if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Process")
            {
                CutoffProcess cs = new CutoffProcess();
                cs.ShowDialog();
            }